# How can I add properties to an object without breaking its parent interface?

Tags: c++, qt

The code base my team and I are working on is used to pilot physical devices (spectrophotometers). They all are very similar but some can do things others cannot do, and they all have their own SDK and drivers.

We often have to support new devices, each of them having their own very specific properties.

The main device interface, say IDevice, has a lot of pure virtual used to determine if devices (say Device1, Device2, etc) can perform a given operation, or what types of operation it supports.

IDevice.h

```
class IDevice : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual ~IDevice() {}
    virtual bool canDoOperationA()   = 0;
    virtual bool canDoOperationB()   = 0;
    virtual QVariant supportedMode() = 0;

    // etc. There are a lot of these ‘canDo’ and ‘supported’ interfaces.

    // dozens of other things, slots, signals, etc.
};
```

Device1.h

```
class Device1 : public IDevice {
public:
     bool canDoOperationA()   { return true; }
     bool canDoOperationB()   { return false; }
     QVariant supportedMode() { return QStringList{{ “m1”, “m2” }}; }
};
```

Device2.h

```
class Device2 : public IDevice {
public:
     bool canDoOperationA()   { return false; }
     bool canDoOperationB()   { return true; }
     QVariant supportedMode() { 
         return getModesAtRuntime(); 
     }

private:
     QVariant getModesAtRuntime() {
         /* determine at runtime what modes are supported,
            depending on the device current configuration */
        return QVariant();
     }
} ;
```

Most of these properties are known at compile time, but some of them, depending on the device, must be determined at runtime (usually through the device SDK, that allows to interrogate the device itself about its status).

On a regular basis, we need to support new devices and / or properties, resulting in the addition of other canDoOperationXXX methods in IDevice (that became monstrous with time). For example, if an operationC and a SpecialMode need to be supported by a specific device, IDevice will become something like:

IDevice.h

```
class IDevice : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     virtual ~IDevice() {}
     virtual bool canDoOperationA() = 0;
     virtual bool canDoOperationB() = 0;
     virtual QVariant supportedMode() = 0;
     virtual bool canDoOperationC() = 0;
     virtual QVariant supportedSpecialMode() = 0;
};
```

All devices then need to be updated and recompiled (and they are not even aware of OperationC and SpecialMode). I think this is a design flaw.

I am wondering if there is an optimal way to add new properties in devices without breaking the API.

I'm thinking of removing all the canDoOperation and supportedModes methods from IDevice and replacing them by the single interface

```
QVariant getProperty(const QString& propertyName) = 0;
```

This way, devices return their own properties, either runtime or compile time. If a property is not supported, an invalid QVariant is returned. Adding a specific property to a specific device won’t break the API, and only the device will be recompiled.

Are there any caveats to this approach? Do you see a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: QObject already has runtime editable properties. See [`QObject::property`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#property) and [`QObject::setProperty`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty)

Comment: @Caleth The problem is that some of the properties cannot be stored, but must be computed at runtime. From what I understand I cannot use QObject::property to achieve this.

Comment: You understand wrong. `QObject::setProperty` with a previously unseen name adds that property. `QObject::property` with a previously unseen name returns an empty `QVariant`

Comment: In some cases I need to read the properties each time from the devices themselves (through their SDKs), because their values change over time. I can set these properties with QObject::setProperty, but every times they change they should be updated. Each device would maintain its own property list.This can be a solution.

Comment: This is a broad topic. There are literally thousand ways to solve that problem. You won't get a satisfying answer other than personal opinions. As an introduction you might want to check the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) and further educate yourself on how to achieve that.

Comment: @fdan Fair point. I'll check the link you provided.

Comment: You can of course provide default implementations that answer `false` for every capability—though that doesn’t prevent needing to recompile the world when adding one.

Comment: Maybe you could consider operations not as methods but rather as callables (or some other wrappers), that derive from an abstract base? Then you could redesign device classes to something like...  `class IDevice
{
 QList<IDeviceOperation> getSupportedDeviceOperations() const = 0;
};` It could be improved with visitor pattern, implemented via some kind of `QVariant performOperation(IDeviceOperation) = 0;` method. Anyway it seems that your solution lies more in OOP plane than in qt.

Comment: @MasterAlef. Agreed. As stated before by fdan, the question is way to broad, and can be answered in thousands of ways. I'll probably never get an answer (a definite one, at least). Is there a way to "close" it?